# Outlook 2016 VBA to make active window (e.g. email) specific size and location on screen

Tags: vba

I have this in Excel, but simply adding the same code into Outlook Module does not do the trick.

```vb
Sub ActiveSize_1()
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.Top = 0
    Application.Left = 972 
    Application.Width = 468 
    Application.Height = 780
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub ActiveSize()
    With Application.ActiveWindow
        .WindowState = olNormalWindow
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 972
        .Width = 468
        .Height = 780
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run that code from custom button of email window - it works on that email window. Which is what I want. When I run that code from custom button of main Outlook window while there is a non active email window, it activates email window and works on that. When I run that code from custom button of main Outlook window I want to only affect the main Outlook window and not any other Outlook window. When I run that code from custom button of main Outlook window, on line .WindowState = olNormalWindow it gives "Run-time error 91. Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Changed `ActiveInspector` to `ActiveWindow` - should have read the title more closely :). I got sidetracked by "(e.g. email)"